# How to display state data in table format in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have a data coming from a API response which is stored in form of array in state. I need to display the data in tabular format.
I am new to React and wanted to know how to display the state data(stored as array) in table format. Shall i create a new component to display the data stored in state?
[image: State data screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"how to display the state data(stored as array) in table format" - Use default html table elements for that.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

"Shall I create a new component to display the data stored in state" - Your question is too wide. You may display whatever you want in any way you want. There is no **the right** way to do it. All depends on what you want to achieve and your code stile. So your question is opinions based most likely that is why you got downvotes.
I would recommend you to create separate components for `<tr>`, `<td>` and `<th>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be reasonable to create a table component and pass in a prop that you'll map through.